# ASP.NET textbox key-up(JS) and TextBoxChaged(Server) event not working simultaneously.

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a text-box in the Gridview, 
and have a javascript function works on textbox keyup, called "`clearNoNum(obj)`" to check up isnumber,

I have registered a textbox event(server side) '`TextBoxChanged`', and the `AutoPostBack=true`

My question is: The server side `TextBoxChange` event would not fired, if have onkeyup javascript function defined on text-box.

Following is my code:

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Number" ItemStyle-Width="100px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbxNumber" AutoPostBack="true" onkeyup="clearNoNum(this)"    runat="server"
                    OnTextChanged="tbxNumber_TextChanged" Text='<%#Eval("Number")%>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
```

jS func:

```
 function clearNoNum(obj) {

    obj.value = obj.value.replace(/[^\d.]/g, "");

    obj.value = obj.value.replace(/^\./g, "");

    obj.value = obj.value.replace(/\.{2,}/g, ".");

    obj.value = obj.value.replace(".", "$#$").replace(/\./g, "").replace("$#$", ".");

}
```

.cs event

```
    protected void tbxNumber_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tbxNumber = (TextBox)sender;
    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)tbxNumber.NamingContainer; 
    Label lblunitsPrice = ((Label)gvr.FindControl("lblunitsPrice"));
    Label lblTotalPrice = ((Label)gvr.FindControl("lblTotalPrice"));
    lblTotalPrice.Text = (int.Parse(lblunitsPrice.Text) * int.Parse(tbxNumber.Text)).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are firing an event(Server) on text-change, it will execute page-life cycle on ever time user release the key, think about how much burden you are putting over server.

It would be better you fire event onblur on text-box. There is an inofrmative answer posted by Josh, you may find it here: [Lost Focus method for asp.net textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863927/lost-focus-method-for-asp-net-textbox)

Comment: i try it , i set return value on the js func,make it still return false,and i write the __dopost like that `(string jsonblur = "if(clearNoNum(this)){__doPostBack('tbxNumber','onkeyup');}";)`,i guess that return value can stop the postBak~but,i am fail~T_T

Comment: i chang the js like `if (isNaN(obj.value)) {do something}else{ setTimeout(dopostback, 0)}` can i restrict the postback like the link u say?