# focus on textbox and call severside method using asp.net web appln

Tags: asp.net

In the below code i have a textbox .My aim is when focus comes in the textbox it has to call the server side method in codebehind using asp.net web application.Pls help me to do this.
design code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtField" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtField_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

code behind:

```
 void txtField_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//code
}
```

Comment: what do want to achieve is unclear.

Comment: @ Șhȇkhaṝ when my focus comes to textbox it has to call the serverside method

Comment: what do want to with the server side method?

Comment: its about event handler

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want full page reload when focusing, make the method a Page Method then use AJAX to invoke it.

For this to work, first of all add reference to the assembly `System.Web.Services` in your project then change the code behind method to:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void txtField_GotFocus()
{
    //code here
}
```

Now to invoke it, my advice is to use jQuery which makes it really easy and simple. Having jQuery included, just have such code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=txtField.ClientID%>").bind("focus", function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<%=Request.FilePath%>/txtField_GotFocus",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                //alert("success message here if you want to debug");
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                var rawHTML = xhr.responseText;
                var strBegin = "<" + "title>";
                var strEnd = "</" + "title>";
                var index1 = rawHTML.indexOf(strBegin);
                var index2 = rawHTML.indexOf(strEnd);
                if (index2 > index1) {
                    var msg = rawHTML.substr(index1 + strBegin.length, index2 - (index1 + strEnd.length - 1));
                    alert("error: " + msg);
                } else {
                    alert("General error, check connection");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And your code behind method will be executed when textbox is focused.

Note that being static, you need to change how you access Request and Response objects (and the likes) for example to access Request, have:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void txtField_GotFocus()
{
    string foo = HttpContext.Current.Request["foo"];
    //code...
}
```

Comment: can u pls tell me how to add web service to my project or have to code the web service

Comment: You don't need web service, the page itself is hosting the method. Do you get any error?

Comment: i got alert("error message here if you want to debug") and pls tell me how to set the url .project name user and i am working on sample.ascx.and we have to set client mode in textbox

Comment: So change to `alert(msg)` and see what the actual error is. Also, set a breakpoint in the code behind, attach debugger and see if it even reach your method.

Comment: @user3224577 sorry, edited now please take the new code and you should now see actual error message. What is this message?

Comment: In alert msg it shows unknown web method txtField_GotFocus<br> parameter name method name

Comment: @user3224577 make sure you added the `static` keyword in the method declaration.

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas. This worked for me when testing. As mentioned by other user there is [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863927/lost-focus-method-for-asp-net-textbox) so maybe you can use the code in there.